# python script from the command line ,the arguments should be a list of options

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I would like to run my python script from the command line when supplies with some arguments. However, one of the arguments should be a list of options specific to a segment of the script.
 Example:
MODULES_TO_INSTALL = ['sale','purchase','account_accountant',]

how can I do this: python fichier.py liste_modules_to_install

Comment: Please share the script, so that will understand how it is accepting the list of arguments

Comment: check this https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar in the past.  It might be easier if instead of sending them as a list already, you call your script like so,

```
python script.py module1 module2 ... moduleN
```

Then a simple line of code to read in these passed modules from command line would be,

```
import sys
MODULES_TO_INSTALL = sys.argv[1:]
```